# How do I change authorization of a site on my Google Appspot OpenID?

Tags: google-app-engine, openid

When I tried to log in to Stack Overflow, I initially used my Google OpenID (which looks like this "http://openid-provider.appspot.com/login") but I accidentally clicked on deny. Now I can't log in with this OpenID at all. Is there any way I can change the authorizations on an account in the future?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

openid-provider.appspot.com is only intended as a demo app! Don't rely on it as a real openid account. As the page itself says:

> Note: this is just an App Engine demo,
>   not the [Google OpenID Provider](https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id)
>   endpoint for the  [Google Federated Login API](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use openid-provider.appspot.com.  Use https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id, which is Google's official OpenID provider.